# Group By multiple fields,but order in the sequential manner

Tags: reporting-services

I have a design question for my SSRS report. I need to design a table in my report which is grouped by multiple field but sort in sequential manner. The table is supposed to be grouped by school name, number, and department, but the table needs to be sort in certificate number. As you can see my table grouped in the right way, but doesnt display by the certificate number.

I created by table with adding parent groups for School name, number, and department, but I am sorting the table in certificate number.

My table:
   [image]

Design table:
[image]

Comment: If it falls under a group.. without having something else to group on ( and separate it), there is no way to take it out of that group.. like the way you want to display.

Comment: Show actual data.. there * might * be a way to do this..

Comment: Sorry this is all I got. I understand that, but I was hoping to find another way to approach it.

Answer (score 0):

easy peasy.

In the groupings pane at the bottom right click on school_name group and got to properties/edit group

then on the left hand side there is sorting option, select it
and choose certificate column from the drop down menu.

Upvote means it worked.

Comment: This will only sort the certificate within the group.. it will not take it out of the group as a separate section like the OP wants.. at least what I gather from his screen shots..

Comment: @harry I want to sort the whole table not separate sections. I start with table sorted in correct order, but as I add more groups, it gets complicated